# Writing an array to a file using python, reading in C++

Tags: python, c++, dataformat

I am generating (np.float64) data in python. This is written in a binary file.
I read the data in C++. I understand if I will read the data in double format, I will get the original data back.
However, when I read the same data in character format, then I get a lot of non-zero values. Although, the original data was just zeros. Why am I getting lots of non-zero values in the character format? I am doing something wrong here? I am not able to understand the basics here.

Code to write in a file (python side):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,4,3,1], dtype=np.float64)
with open("temp.txt", "wb") as binary_file:
    # Write bytes to file
    for values in a:
       binary_file.write(values)
```

Code to read in C++:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include "compression.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Need filename" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    // enable check against decompress
    bool CHECK_ERR = true;
    std::string file(argv[1]);
    std::ifstream input(file, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    std::streampos size;
    size = input.tellg();
    input.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
      
    // Reading data as double 
    std::vector<double> fileData(size/sizeof(double));
    input.read((char*) &fileData[0], size);
    // This will generate the correct values, which I need
    for (int i=0; i<fileData.size(); i++ )
     cout<< fileData.at(i)<<" ";
    cout << endl;
    
    // Reading data in character format
    std::ifstream inputChr(file, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
   inputChr.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    while(size >= 64)
    {
      char memblock[64];
      inputChr.read((char*) &memblock, 64);
      cout << "Character values "<< endl;
      for (int i=0; i<64; i++)
          cout  << +(memblock[i]) << "  ";
      cout << endl;
      size--;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your actual code also first read the entire file and then keep reading past the end forever? (Please post a [mcve].)

Comment: Unrelated, but it is pointless to specify `std::ios::in` on a `std::ifstream`.

Comment: Do you handle the endieness of your system?

Comment: @Unlikus Endianness does not matter for zero values in IEEE 64 bit format.

Comment: Presumable the problem is as molbdnilo says, you need to rewind the get pointer to the beginning of your file before you start the character format read.

Comment: Be careful I would do: `input.read((char*) &fileData[0], size/sizeof(double)*size);` to avoid any issues with a size that is not exactly the correct size.

Comment: Inside this loop: `while(size >= 64)` where do you decrement `size`? Also `inputChr.read((char*) &memblock, 64)` may not always read `64` bytes (you have to check).